# Why I cannot render the spinner (.gif) in my html with ReactJs?

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to disable the button and show the spinner when user clicks on the button. The code is below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        submitted: false,
        loading: false,
        error: ''
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    ...
}


render(){
 return(
  ...
  <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" disabled={this.state.loading}>
   Login
  </Button>
  {
   this.state.loading &&
   <img alt="" src="loading.gif" />
  }
  ... )
```

The problem here is that when I add in the `src` the `favicon.ico` it renders it, but if I try to add any image (.jpg or .gif) nothing happens. I also have the .gif in the same folder of the `LoginPage.js`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import your image before using it :

```
 import spinner from "path/loading.gif"
```

and then render like this :

```
<img alt="" src={spinner} />
```

Comment: In addition to this, you will also need a loader (assuming they are using Webpack) to handle .gif files. If they are using something like create-react-app, then this will be handled automatically :)

Comment: @adel even if I have the image in the same folder? and yes that's the way...I didn't  know it thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheodoreTsg import like this :  `import spinner from "./loading.gif"`

Comment: @adel yeap I know how...the only thing I was missing was to import it...thnx again

Comment: @adel is there any explanation why my favicon.ico renders while I don't import it?

Comment: because here your are writing jsx not html wich work like js so you need to import your local file before using, if  your file was on the server you could loaded it with a url but here your file is local on your machine!